# i need to change html tags to erb so what this code should be in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<img src="/assets/slider/slider-bg-1.jpg"  alt="" data-lazyload="/assets/slider/slider-bg-1.jpg" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
```

My problem is this would not recognize my image with any of the solutions for precompiling or other stuff in production environment and I need to change all my img tags to something rails understands

Comment: Ill try and respond , tnx

Comment: data:{lazyload: "<%= asset_path('slider-bg-1.jpg') %>"
this part has syntax error

Comment: `<%= image_tag("slider-bg-1.jpg", data:{lazyload:  asset_path("slider-bg-1.jpg"), bgposition: "center top", bgfit: "cover" , bgrepeat: "no-repeat"}) %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i saw the first solution i got the idea to use the image_path helper and it did work in both erb and scss .
Justl like a href=" image_path('image.jpg')"
And in scss like url=( image_path('image.png'))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= image_tag("/assets/slider/slider-bg-1.jpg", data:{lazyload: asset_path("/assets/slider/slider-bg-1.jpg"), bgposition: "center top", bgfit: "cover" , bgrepeat: "no-repeat"}) %>
```

Comment: Guys after i tried the first solution , i got this idea to just put the image_path helper to work in my htmls and it did work and for my scss these works too without even changing the extension.  Src=( Image_path('slider/slider.jpg')) like this